# Css grid layout with unknown of columns / same width

Tags: html, css, vue.js, css-grid

I am creating a navigation bar with grids.
In short, when user is admin he will have two more links at the end, that should be the same width and not dependent on the amount of text like it is now. I am using vue.

*I removed **tags attributes** for simplicity*

**hint:** the purple lines dont exist in css it's just grid layout for debuging

1) user is not admin, the search bar takes 1 fraction
[image: Not admin]
2) user is admin, the search bar is 1fr, the other two are auto
[image]

```
<section id="masthead">
        <button>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </button>
        <div>
            <span>Logo</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="search" id="search">
            <button id="loupe">O</button>
        </div>

        <!-- show links if Admin -->
        <div><span>Submit Video</span></div> 
        <div><span>Profile</span></div>
</section>
```

here is the CSS

```
#masthead {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 75px 100px 1fr auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-column-gap: 10px;
    height: 56px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.22);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

How Can i make the last two links be the **same width** when they exist in view.
I want dynamic columns :)

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried 1fr for the two admin items, and something like 8fr for the search bar? When the admin items are not present, the value of the search fr doesn’t matter.

Comment: @Michael_B Still it creates large empty space if i add 1fr for admin items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by using this css:

```
#masthead {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 75px 75px 0.9fr;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    height: 56px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.22);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

It's not perfect but it gets the job done:
[image: without admin items]
[image: with admin items]